# Gridview alignment of elements

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a `grid view` with 7 images, and now when I inflate it I get it like this
[image]

Here you can see the images are aligned as per normal view
But I dont want it like that I want it like this

[image]

The bottom images are aligned to form kind of a pyramid or triangle type
How can i achieve this in gridview in android ???

Comment: I think the main point of a GridView is prevent this exact scenario. You second picture is not a grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to set the padding then you get the view to be shrinked like this

```
if(position == 4){
    view.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

[image]

So I would suggest something like this

1. Create 2 gridviews in xml as this such that they have their alignments centered

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txtControl"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:text=""
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   <GridView
       android:id="@+id/gridView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/txtControl"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:numColumns="4" >
   </GridView>

   <GridView
       android:id="@+id/gridView2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/txtControl"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:numColumns="3" >
   </GridView>
   ```
2. Now In your main activity create 2 String values for each

   public class MainActivityWrapped extends Activity {

   ```
   static final String[] MOBILE_OS1 = new String[] { 
       "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "Blackberry"};
   static final String[] MOBILE_OS2 = new String[] { 
       "Android", "iOS", "Windows"};

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.gridviewlayout);
       GridView gridView1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);        
       gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterWrapped(this, MOBILE_OS1,gridView1));
       GridView gridView2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);        
       gridView2.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterWrapped(this, MOBILE_OS2,gridView1));

   }
   ```

   }

   Either you can create 2 adapter or control the same 1st adapter to be reused

   The output would be like this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Takendarkk comments, the layout you want is not a grid

You should be able to achieve what you want with nested linearlayouts:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       <!-- first 4 image views here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       <!-- last 3 image views here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The image size changes due to difference in number, And I dont want to define size in dp, and off all I cant use my adapter here

Comment: ok you might want to edit your question to claify - you've not mentioned wanting to use an adapter, and you've specified that you have a fixed amount of 7 images

Comment: If you use a grid view or list view then you have to use an adapter to feed the data, you cant do it in any other manner. pls read your basics first

Comment: drop the attitude if you expect help

Answer (score 0):

This is do-able, but the solution is messy.

If you know how many images are going to be in the row, you can calculate how much padding you'll need on the left and right images of your row.

Then, in your `getView()` of your adapter, you can set this padding bearing in mind that due to the way views are recycled in adapters, you'll need to unset the padding for those that do not need it.

Let me know in a comment if you need some code to better illustrate what I'm proposing.